# jboss 6 dojo error 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: rest, jboss, dojo

I know this error is quite common, but all things i've read and tried and nothing works.

```
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
//@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
//@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String test() {
    return "{\"name\":\"stewie\"}";
}
```

And in dojo

```
xhr("/CSH/rest/test/", {
    handleAs : "json"
    // headers: {"Accept", "application/json"}      
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

It works perfectly fine in tomcat 7. But not in JBoss 6.

Please note that i am not using resteasy, but jersey.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any thrown Exception ! 
and in client side add the error claback function to show if there were an error `[xhr(...).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, function(error){console.log(error)});]`

Comment: @bRIMOsBor No. Jboss log is clean. all i get is the error from firebug: GET http://localhost:7070/CSH/rest/test/
 
415 Unsupported Media Type
  71ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it all comes down to this: dojo sucks. How come in the official documentation you find things tagged with "not known at this time" ?

The answer to my problem was to switch to jquery. Here and there i had to specify dataType="json" in the call and that was it.